# Is there a way to link react-redux and react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have an app that uses url parameters to change the data that is displayed on the page.

At the moment, I'm using react-router and react-redux. The react-router passes the parameters to a component in the route:

```
<Route path='/annotations/:sessionId/:eventId' render={route => 
       <AnnotationPage sessionId={route.match.params.sessionId} eventId={route.match.params.eventId} />} />
```

Then, that component passes those values to my `ActionCreator` which calls the server and updates the state based on the passed in `sessionId` and `eventId`.

The issues I see with this:

- Someone could call the `ActionCreator` and change `eventId` or `sessionId` without updating the URL parameters
- There are now two IDs stored. The one that is in the state (set by the `ActionCreator`), and one in the URL

I'd like the URL parameters to be the "source of truth" in my application, but I'm not sure of an elegant way of doing that. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/Treora/redux-query-sync

Comment: you can check the params and then show suitable error to user !

Comment: @TylerFindlay if you are looking for a library, [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) should be a good choice,

You dont really need a library to do this though, the guide is right here : [usage-with-react-router](https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to update this for anyone who may have encountered it. I ended up implementing something similar to @winwiz1 suggested, but more `connected-react-router` specific.

I wasn't able to ever had a location change trigger a server request, but by having a timeout to check when the filter variables change and having filter variables change based on the URL, I get what I'm looking for.

store.ts

```
import { LocationChangeAction } from 'connected-react-router';
...
export type FilterActions = 
    | LocationChangeAction
...
export const placeItemListReducer: Reducer<IPlaceItemListState, FilterActions> = (
    state = initialPlaceListState,
    action,
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE': {
            if (placePageRegex.test(action.payload.location.pathname)) {
                const toParse: string = action.payload.location.pathname
                    .replace('/order', '')
                    .replace('/menu', '')
                    .replace('/edit', '');
                const newFsiUrl: string = toParse.substring(toParse.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                if (newFsiUrl === state.placefsiUrlFilter && 
                    state.version === currStoreVersion) {
                    return state;
                }
                else {
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        version: currStoreVersion,
                        placefsiUrlFilter: newFsiUrl,
                        place: null,
                        placeItems: [],
                        lastFilterChangeEpochMilliseconds: Date.now(),
                        productsPerPage: stringNullEmptyOrUndefined(newFsiUrl) ? state.productsPerPage : 500,
                    };
                }
            }
            else {
                return state;
            }
        }
...
```

sync.ts

```
export const startSyncIntervalActionCreator: ActionCreator<
    ThunkAction<
        Promise<void>,      // The type of the last action to be dispatched - will always be promise<T> for async actions
        IAppState,          // The type for the data within the last action
        string,             // The type of the parameter for the nested function 
        ISyncSuccessAction  // The type of the last action to be dispatched
    >
> = () => {
    return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, AnyAction>) => {
        if (timer !== undefined) {
            return;
        }
        
        timer = setInterval(() => dispatch(syncActionCreator()), 100);
    };
};
...
export const syncActionCreator: ActionCreator<
    ThunkAction<
        Promise<void>,      // The type of the last action to be dispatched - will always be promise<T> for async actions
        IAppState,          // The type for the data within the last action
        string,             // The type of the parameter for the nested function 
        ISyncSuccessAction  // The type of the last action to be dispatched
    >
> = () => {
    return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, AnyAction>, getState: () => IAppState) => {
        if (getState().syncState.currentlySyncing) {
            return;
        }

        const millisecondsSinceLastSync: number = (getCurrentTimeEpochMilliseconds() - getState().placeItemListState.lastSyncEpochMilliseconds);
        const hasDataTimeout: boolean = millisecondsSinceLastSync > dataTimeoutPeriodMilliseconds;
        if (getState().placeItemListState.lastSyncEpochMilliseconds <= getState().placeItemListState.lastFilterChangeEpochMilliseconds ||
                hasDataTimeout) {
            const startPlaceItemSyncAction: IStartPlaceItemSyncAction = {
                type: 'StartPlaceItemSync',
                fromDataTimeout: hasDataTimeout,
            };
            dispatch(startPlaceItemSyncAction);

            axios.post(
                process.env.REACT_APP_API_ROOT_URL + 'PlaceItem/sync-flat',
                {
                    fsiUrlFilter: getState().placeItemListState.placefsiUrlFilter,
                    searchTerms: getState().searchTermsState.placeItemSearchTerms,
                    tagIds: getState().toggleFilterState.placeItemTags.filter(f => f.selected).map(f => f.id),
                    pageNumber: getState().placeItemListState.pageNum,
                    productsPerPage: getState().placeItemListState.productsPerPage,
                },
                {
                    headers: { 
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${getState().authState.authToken}`,
                    }
                }
            ).then((res: AxiosResponse<IPlaceItemSyncFlatResponse>) => {
                const syncResponse: IPlaceItemSyncFlatResponse = res.data;
                const syncSuccessAction: IPlaceItemSyncSuccessAction = {
                    type: 'PlaceItemSyncSuccess',
                    syncTimestampEpochMilliseconds: startSyncTime,
                    placeData: res.data.placeData,
                    placeItems: syncResponse.placeItems,
                    extraCategories: syncResponse.extraCategories,
                    extras: syncResponse.extras,
                    currentMenuCategories: syncResponse.menuCategories,
                    tags: syncResponse.tags,
                    totalNumberOfPlaces: syncResponse.totalNumberOfPlaces,
                    restaurantOrders: syncResponse.orderFromLast5Days,
                };
                dispatch(syncSuccessAction);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

syncWrapper.ts (make sure the application is wrapped in this component as it starts the sync timeout)

```
...
interface IProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    startSync: () => void,
}

const SyncWrapper: React.FC<IProps> = ({
    children,
    startSync,
}) => {
    startSync();

    return (
        <>{children}</>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (store: IOfflineAppState) => {
    return {
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, AnyAction>) => {
    return {
        startSync: () => dispatch(startSyncIntervalActionCreator()),
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(SyncWrapper);
```

Answer (score 1):

When `location` changes, react-router-redux dispatches an action with type set to `"@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE"`. This string is exported as `LOCATION_CHANGE` so it can be imported:

```js
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux'
```

A reducer can process this action and augment state with location:

```js
case LOCATION_CHANGE:
  return { ...state, ...action.payload };
```

Then the URL parameters, being a part of Redux state, become the "source of truth" in your application.

P.S.

- [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) doesn't dispatch `LOCATION_CHANGE` action.
- [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) does dispatch `LOCATION_CHANGE` action so you can intercept it and decide which pieces of data (contained in the `payload` of this action) you want to add to Redux store. But the router is no longer maintained.
- [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) does dispatch `LOCATION_CHANGE` action. You would not want to intercept this action to augment Redux store with the data contained in its `payload` because the router does it anyway. That is, it augments Redux store automatically. But you might want to intercept `LOCATION_CHANGE` action for other purposes. [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html) can use its `take/takeEvery/takeLatest/takeLeading` to intercept `LOCATION_CHANGE` action and respond with one or more async and non-async actions of your choosing such as fetching, dispatching other action(s) to Redux store etc.

Comment: I'm still not totally clear on how you would capture this in a reducer. Also, ideally the change in location would trigger an action creator, but I could set this up in the store file. Then, I would just not export that action creator so it couldn't be called through the rest of the application. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: react-router-redux already has an embedded action creator which dispatches an action with `action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE`. Since you use Redux, you already have a reducer which likely contains  `switch` with `case`s. Simply add `case LOCATION_CHANGE: ` to it and the statement `{ ...state, ...action.payload }` will inject goodies from payload including `payload.path` into Redux state.

Comment: Because the change in URL needs to not only change the state, but also perform some other actions (fetch data from the server) I would prefer that the URL change trigger an action creator.

So the flow I want is:

url change --> custom Action Creator dispatched (fetch data from service) --> action dispatched to update state variables

Comment: @TylerFindlay Then consider using [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html). It's a very good package that can intercept LOCATION_CHANGE action and perform one or several actions in response including an async action, such as your fetch, and dispatching another your custom action to Redux store. Time spent on learning redux-saga will be rewarding as you will feel empowered by its capabilities which greatly enhance the toolset of any developer using Redux.

Answer (score 0):

This is a logic based question.

Since you and your developers are in control of the code the best you can do is to document that action creator and make sure you call it only with the params gotten from the url. Trying to tie the URL as a `source of truth` to your code can still possibly lead to the scenario in which you have duplicate data eventid and sessionid, that's if the user changes the URL params and refresh the page. So You should instead at the server perform the check to make sure the eventid and sessionid are from the correct sources and have not been manipulated. Or that there are no two Ids stored.